# "It will be more of a sucks for him ..."

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I've seen the disparaging sense of *sucks* as a verb ("sucks to be you", "that sucks!"), but this particular usage from *Price Caspian* seems a little odd:

> Lucy heard Edmund say, "No, let me do it. It will be more of a sucks for him if I win, and less of a let-down for us all if I fail."

[My interpretation](http://www.anamardoll.com/2012/06/narnia-lashing-out-at-little-people.html) was that *It'll be a sucks for him* is intended to convey "It will be a victory for us", with strong implications of humiliation and embarrassment for Trumpkin.

However, I can't find a dictionary definition which *quite* matches this use of the word.

> **eat crow**, *Informal*. to be forced to admit to having made a mistake, as by retracting an emphatic statement; suffer humiliation: *His prediction was completely wrong, and he had to eat crow.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [OED](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=583268), *sucks* was an interjection of contempt for children from the early 20th century:

> 11. pl. as int. Used as an expression of
>   contempt, chiefly by children. Also in
>   phr. sucks to you and varr. slang.
>   1913 C. MACKENZIE Sinister Street I. I. vii.
>   98 This kid's in our army, so sucks! 1922
>   F. HAMILTON P.J.: Secret Service Boy iv. 178 ‘S’, he announced, ‘u,c,k,s,t,o,y,o,u.’
>   1935 N. MITCHISON We have been
>   Warned I. 28 Brian is a baby. Oh sucks,
>   oh sucks on Brian. 1945 E. WAUGH
>   Brideshead Revisited II. v. 287 It's great
>   sucks to Bridey. 1952 ‘C. BRAND’ London Particular xv. 191 A most regretable air
>   of sucks to you. 1968 Melody Maker 30
>   Nov. 24/5 This is a rotten recordyah boo
>   and sucks. 1974 Times 4 Mar. 9/5 Sucks
>   boo, then, with acting like this, to that
>   new National Theatre down the road. 1978 ‘J. LYMINGTON’ Waking of Stone ii.
>   45 ‘Sucks to you!’ she said..tossing her
>   head so her pigtails swung. 1983
>   Listener 19 May 11/1 The council
>   treated the urbane Mr Cook to the
>   politician's equivalent of ‘Yah, boo, sucks’.

These are all notably British quotations.

Answer (score 2):

This usage appears memorably in William Golding's novel [*Lord of the Flies*](http://books.google.com/books?id=mlo6gmuq0Y4C&lpg=PT14&dq=sucks%20to%20your%20ass-mar&pg=PT14#v=onepage&q=sucks%20to%20your%20ass-mar&f=false) (1954):

> "I can't swim.  I wasn't allowed.  My asthma—"
>
> "Sucks to your ass-mar!"

The speakers in this dialogue are British schoolboys.  As in Hugo's answer, the intention is clearly to express contempt.  *Sucks* is used repeatedly throughout the novel and becomes something of a catch phrase.

I think this is distinct from the modern usage of *suck* as a verb.  The noun seems to be much more mild, as it was chiefly used by children.  In contrast, the modern *suck* started out quite offensive (as a reference to fellatio) but has softened over time and been picked up by children and teens.

Answer (score 1):

So far as I can see, OP's citation from C.S.Lewis's 1951 [Prince Caspian](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6xxbAAAAMAAJ&q=%22Lucy%20heard%20Edmund%20say%22&dq=%22Lucy%20heard%20Edmund%20say%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=FUXqT-f4PI298gPl48hn&ved=0CEAQ6AEwAg) is a complete one-off. Or at least, that 'noun' usage probably hasn't existed for generations - it's invariably a verb today.

Googling today's Internet, I can't find a single instance of ["a sucks for me"](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22a+sucks+for+me%22&oq=%22a+sucks+for+me%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=hp.12...0.0.1.477109.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0.8p0WYOEsRzQ&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=3949f674911d0ae9&biw=1538&bih=843) used in this noun sense, as in *"The whole day was a sucks for me"* (but there are plenty for ["The whole day sucked for me"](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22The+whole+day+sucked+for+me%22&oq=%22The+whole+day+sucked+for+me%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=hp.3...8279.10373.1.10877.10.10.0.0.0.0.115.770.8j2.10.0...0.0.dhTZi54UWVw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=3949f674911d0ae9&biw=1538&bih=843)).

Comment: *Generations* is an exaggeration; I remember using the phrase at primary school. And the (American) *that sucks* is subtly different; an unpleasant experience, but without the implication of defeat for you (and so victory for others) in *sucks to you*.

Comment: The use of it as a noun ("a sucks") is rare, but as the quotations Hugo reproduces show, the interjection is by no means obsolete.

Comment: @Colin Fine: Hugo quotes *"So sucks on Brian!"* (1945), and *"Sucks to you!"* (1983), but I'm not sure they're such a clear-cut noun usage as OP's version. I maintain that OP's citation is well and truly obsolete today, particularly given that the verb form *("Aw, man! That really sucks!")* has now become really common. There's nothing odd about *"Sucks to you!"* even today, but *"It's a sucks for you!"* is a complete no-no for me.

Comment: Most usages of "suck" are a complete no-no for me, simply due to their origin. @FumbleFingers

Answer (score 1):

I think you're parsing the sentence wrong. Here is how I interpret it:

> No, let me do it. It will be more of a "sucks for him" (situation) if I win, and less of a "let-down for us all" (situation) if I fail.

So it is using the more familiar "*that (situation) sucks for (someone)*", and inserting it whole into the sentence to contrast the two possible outcomes.